# fabricjs clippath not working as per size

Tags: fabricjs

I am trying to apply clippath on image, i am passing rect as clippath to image and size of rect is same as image including scale, still after apply clippath image cropped like clipath is less then what we applied.
i have checked clippath scaled width , height after apply is still same but image is clipped bit small like given in attached image.

```
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
              left: 0,
              top: 0,
              width: obj.getScaledWidth(),
              height: obj.getScaledHeight(),
              originX: 'center',
              originY: 'center'
            });
    rect.setCoords();
    obj.clipPath = rect;
    obj.clipPath.dirty = true;
    obj.dirty = true; canvas.renderAll();
```

My fabric version is 3.4.0.

original image on left side and after apply same size rect as clippath clipped image on right side, actual result should be same size image without any clipped part
[image]

one thing i have noticed is cacheHeight and cacheWidth of clipath is less then width and height of clippath. please find below screenshot, is it reason for that, if then what will be solution?
[image]

Comment: Were you able to solve this?